# Is it true that the marginal expectation of a probablity density function is still a probablity density?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $p(x,y),x,y\in \Bbb R$ be a probability density function. Let $q(x),x \in \Bbb R$ be another density.

1. Is $f(y)=\Bbb E_q[p(x,y)] = \int q(x)p(x,y)dx$ a density function?
2. Is $f(y)=\exp\{\Bbb E_q [\log p(x,y)]\}$ a density function?

I am not sure, but my hunch is that it is not necessarily true. Take 1.  for example, if it is probability density, then $\int f(y)dy=\int{\int q(x)p(x,y)dxdy}=\int q(x) (\int p(x,y)dy) dx=\int q(x) p_X(x) dx=1$ where $p_X$ is the marginal density of $p$. Since $p,q$ has no relation, I think the product of two arbitrary density functions might not be a density.

I would appreciate it if someone can help with concrete counterexamples.

Comment: Good intuition.  If you can find a discrete counterexample, say by letting $X$ and $Y$ take on 2 values each, with joint distribution specified by 4 probabilities  adding up to 1, you can probably boost it to an example on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by convolving everything with uniform distributions.